# Check if child with specific title exist

Tags: jquery

I want to check if there is a child with a specific title under my parent.,
I've managed to check if children exists, but I want to add a check if the title equals the string "No"..

```
$(this).find('#test').children().size() === 0;
```

How can this be done?

Comment: by title, you mean title attribute or html of the child...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$(this).find('#test').children('[title=No]').length > 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this: `$('[title="No"]', this);`

To explain, this will look for an element with `title="No"` *inside* `this`, which will be your current element in a loop, or can be another selector altogether.